# Checking whether last element of list is digit

Tags: python

I have a function generating random character [a-Z0-9] with whitespaces and appending each character to `list`:

```
words = []

while words.count(' ') < 10:
    if len(words) == 0:
        # append character
    else:
        if words[-1].isdigit(): # checking if last character is digit
            # append only digit or whitespacce
        else:
            # append character
```

As you can see if last (previous) character was digit, I try to append digit or whitespace only, otherwhise append any character. The problem is, when I run the code I get error below:

`'NoneType' object has no attribute 'isdigit'` for line `if words[-1].isdigit():`. What I do wrong and why there is `None` instead of `str`?

Comment: `words` must contain `None` in its last place.

Comment: To debug add a line that prints `words` immediately after the while loop. If that doesn't help you debug, edit the question with the entire output. As others have mentioned, `words[-1]` is evaluating to `None`

Comment: Can you include the code you use to append characters to `words`? It seems you're appending `None` objects to `words` list, hence the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make `words` string:

(It's biased towards chars, because whitespace is not digit, and hence it can turn to chars from digits, but not other way around- which is what you wanted, if I got you right)

```py
import random

sample_digit=" 0123456789"
sample_char=" abcdefghi"
sample_any=sample_digit+sample_char
words = ""
while words.count(' ') <10:
    if len(words) == 0:
        words+=sample_any[random.randint(0, len(sample_any)-1)]
    else:
        if words[-1].isdigit():
            words+=sample_digit[random.randint(0, len(sample_digit)-1)]
        else:
            words+=sample_char[random.randint(0, len(sample_char)-1)]

print(words)
```

Answer (score -1):

A simple way of testing whether a character is a digit:

```py
if words[-1] in '0123456789':
    ...
```

Comment: returns `'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not NoneType`

Comment: You could use [**`string.digits`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.digits). However, `'0123' in string.digits` will return `True` and `'3210' in string.digits` will return `False`.

Comment: None of this helps that `words[-1].isdigit()` would work if `words[-1]` weren't `None`.